# Url rewrite to takeout

Tags: php, .htaccess

Good days guys, I need your help with this url rewrite.

The are two rewrites I want to do.

1) I want to take out `.php` from the url even though my files is saved as `.php`

2) I want to rewrite the url below

```
www.example/account/product.php?Sef=shoes&pid=3
```

To something like this

```
www.example/account/product.php?Sef=shoes/pid/3
```

If you can help me. It will be lovely. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your second problem you don't need htaccess for that just parse `$_GET['Sef']` on your server side.
As per php extension try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I have update my question to show all my rewrites because your code doesn't take off `.php` from any file in the `url`